# plotting points as function of date

Tags: python, date, plot

I've got a file list with earthquake dates, longitudes and magnitudes, like follows:

```
2015-11-12    22.86    5.20
2015-11-18    15.12    4.25
2015-11-20    12.91    7.85
..........    .....    ....
```

and I'd like to plot points on a graph, with a color that depends on the magnitude `mag`, with `date` parameter on the x-axis and longitude `long` on the y-axis. I'm trying to do this, but the difficult part is making the script read the date as a number... Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at `numpy` and `pandas` modules, that have many functionalities to get statistical data and plot them.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you're using **matplotlib** to generate graphics and the **ritcher scale** to measure earthquake magnitude, we can use the scatter plot to each point. A helper function allow us to select the desired color according the point value. The resulting code is as follows:

```
import math
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Function to convert
def obterCor(valor):
   cores = {2.0: '#37e52b', 2.9: '#1887bf', 3.9: '#1745d1', 4.9: '#e9ed1e', 5.9: '#f79c09', 6.9: '#f76409', 7.9: '#ff0000', 8.9: '#ea17c7', 100.0: '#9800ff'}
   cor = '#37e52b'
   for k,v in sorted(cores.iteritems()):
       if valor <= k:
           cor = v
           break
   return cor

#Data
linhas = [ x.strip() for x in open('arquivo.txt', 'r') ]
x = []
y = []
z = []
for l in linhas:
   l = l.split()
   x.append( datetime.strptime(l[0], "%Y-%m-%d") )
   y.append( float(l[1]) )
   z.append( obterCor( float(l[2]) ))

#Plotting
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Longitude')
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the date with a number by using timestamps. The datetime modules has useful functions for this. Look for datetime.strptime.
In your case it would be

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(your_date, '%Y-%m-%d').timestamp()
```

if you do this for all dates you get a nice representation. The ticks will be ugly though, you you will have to solve that manually. There probably are functions of plotting modules that circumvent the whole issues of transcribing the dates to numbers, so it might be worth looking into that.